How to find the correct ticker name for Google finance formula's Currency Data?
A question the forex data in googlesheet, I'm using the formula below to get all columns of Open-High-Low-Close.
Will somebody can elaborate how these values are calculated(stand for)? It's not the usual  pair rate to another currency, and the values difference quite a bit in different currencies. I asked this to AI, it answered the value are based on a chunk of currencies, but nothing specific.
Do these data have any practical use on forex trading?
Thank You!
=GOOGLEFINANCE("USD","ALL",TODAY()-366*3,TODAY())



Make sure to provide input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Check my answer or other options to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

To get the ticker name to use in the formula, search Google finance website directly. For eg, USD stands for ProShares Ultra Semiconductors. The exact ticker name can usually be found in the url. For the currency pair USD/CAD, the link is
https://www.google.com/finance/quote/USD-CAD

Therefore, the ticker name is USD-CAD from the last part of the url.
=GOOGLEFINANCE("USD-CAD")

For a specific exchange, you may need to prefix with the exchange information, eg: NASDAQ:TSLA
